# How to compile and run Java with single command line on Windows

Tags: java, windows, command

Everytime I want to build and run my program I do:

```
javac myProgram.java
java myProgram
```

I want to do something like this:

```
buildrun = javac (some_argument).java && java (some_argument)
```

so after I can just

```
buildrun myProgram
```

How to achieve this on Windows?

Comment: .cmd file should solve your problem

Comment: In this case, of course, it is better to use build tools

Comment: A batch file maybe? Or just use an IDE...

Answer (score 2):

As other's have suggested you can simply create a batch file to build and run your program. Copy this in Notepad and save as .bat.

```
@echo off
set /p class="Enter Class: "
javac "%class%".java
java "%class%"
```

As you want, the batch file will ask for a FileName when it runs. In your case, you can set it to 'myProgram' and it will then compile and run the program.

Just make sure your batch file and your java file reside in the same folder for this script to run. You can always tweak the bat file to even accept the full path of the Java file.

Answer (score 1):

To compile and run Java with single command line in cmd use:
java myProgram.java

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Makefile` this way:

1. Create a file named `Makefile` within the same folder where your java files reside.
2. Add these contents to `Makefile`

```
run: compile
    java $(class)

compile: 
    javac $(class).java
```

3. From terminal, run this command:
   `make run class=myProgram`

This way, it will compile first then run your java class in a single command

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution. Create `buildrun.cmd` file with the following code:

```
@echo off
javac %1.java
if errorlevel = 0 goto RUN

:ERROR
echo "Build fails!"
goto END

:RUN
java %1

:END
```

Now you can pass the class name which should be processed. For example:  `buildrun MyProgram` to compile `MyProgram.java` and run `MyProgram.class`
In this case execution will performs only if your class was compiled successful.